# Kotlin: Cannot reassign LatLng's latitude/longitude

Tags: android, kotlin, geolocation

Let's say I have 2 `LatLng` variables.

```
lateinit var mLatLng1:LatLng
lateinit var mLatLng2:LatLng
```

Let's say they've both already been initialized to some values.

If I try this:

```
mLatLng1 = mLatLng2
```

It works as expected. However, when i try this:

```
mLatLng1.latitude = mLatLng2.latitude
```

I get an error:

> Val cannot be reassigned

If my `mLatLng1` variable is of type `var`, then why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If my mLatLng1 variable is of type var, then why am I getting this error?

Because you are not assigning something to `mLatLng1`. That would be:

```
mLatLng1 = LatLng(45.0, 123.0)
```

Instead, you are doing this:

```
mLatLng1.latitude = mLatLng2.latitude
```

This is attempting to update a field *inside* `mLatLng1`. And, if your object is [this `LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng), those fields are `final`, which in Kotlin maps to `val`.